# NStableview setDatasource EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Im trying to just create a simple menu with an NSTableView using an NSarray. When i set the data source to the class i created i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Wierd thing is, it worked in macruby?
implementation file:

```
@implementation TableArray

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hey", @"what", @"there", nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
{
    return [arr count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn      *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [arr objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

@end
```

Header:

```
@interface TableArray: NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource> {
   NSArray *arr;    
} 

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;
- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn  *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
@end
```

And in the app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    TableArray *arr = [[TableArray alloc] init];
    [tv setDataSource:arr];
    [tv reloadData];
}
```

And the delegate header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
   IBOutlet NSTableView *tv;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: You haven't initialised tv, nil targered messages should be ignored.

Comment: tv is an IBOutlet to the tableview made in interface builder. I also have ARC enabled. The program crashing is the main problem.

Comment: Pretty sure what's happening is something like this: you instantiate a `TableArray`, assign it as the `dataSource` of `tv` (which is a weak property) and then after that, no strong references to `arr` exists so it's deallocated. Retain `arr` somewhere to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting you have ARC enabled (possibly GC).   NSTableView maintains a weak reference to its data source and you aren't maintaining a strong reference to same, so ARC is releasing your data source before you are done with.

Note that it is exceptionally rare to have a data source float about like this.  It is almost assuredly a part of the control layer of your app since the data source is the conduit between the table and the underlying data store.

It likely works under MacRuby because the code is slightly different or because of implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know where you are initializing *tv. I'm assuming you've placed it in some NIB file that gets loaded at app startup.
Then, you should put `IBOutlet NSTableView *tv;` in a ViewController, ideally one that subclasses `UITableViewController`. a tableView reference/outlet belongs there.
Also, it would be easier to use the viewController itself as dataSource, and make the connection in Interface Builder.

Comment: I have that -_- already. Im just trying to set up a a simple menu using an array a la the itunes menu. It worked in macruby doing pretty much the same thing. Its a mac os x app not an ios one.

Comment: Oh, well... you can't know what happens behind the scenes in MacRuby